# undefined method `unserialize_attribute' in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am working on upgrading rails application, I have a method  `unserialize_attribue` in `rails 3` but I am not able to see this method in `rails 5`.

What is the alternative for `unserialize_attribute` in rails 5 or any suggestion on what can I do, Thanks

Comment: How do you want your unserialised attribute to look like?

Comment: How does your unserialised attribute look like in rails 3?

Comment: I am trying to update to rails 3.2.22 from 3.1.12, but still getting error of `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in 'alias_method': undefined method 'unserialize_attribute' for class `ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)`. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using [serializable_hash](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serialization/serializable_hash) and it is available in `rails 3` as well as in `rails 5`

I have this code written in rails 3

```
unserialized_value = unserialize_attribute(options[:serialized_column]) || { }
```

which I changed to

```
unserialized_value = self.serializable_hash[options[:serialized_column]] || { }
```

both method returns the same hash object.

Comment: I am not clear how it can be solution for question you asked, but glad that it worked for you. If you explain how many changes you did, it will be great

Answer (score 5):

`unserialize_attribute` is removed from `rails-5` but you can unserialized value in different way,

**Method:1**

```
> @user.accessible_attribute
# => {"attr1"=>["Email id"], "attr2"=>["First Name"], "attr3"=>["Last Name"]}

> @user.attributes_before_type_cast['accessible_attribute']
# => "--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\nattr1:\n- Email id\nattr2:\n- First Name\nattr3:\n- Last Name\n"
```

**Method:2**

```
@user.instance_variable_get(:@attributes)['accessible_attribute'].value_before_type_cast
# => "--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\nattr1:\n- Email id\nattr2:\n- First Name\nattr3:\n- Last Name\n"
```

**Method:3**

```
> @accessible_attribute = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT accessible_attribute FROM users WHERE id = #{@user.id}")
   (0.4ms)  SELECT accessible_attribute FROM users WHERE id = 3
# => #<Mysql2::Result:0xe0fc374 @query_options={:as=>:array, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:utc, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>-2147442171, :cast=>true, :default_file=>nil, :default_group=>nil, :adapter=>"mysql2", :encoding=>"utf8mb4", :collation=>"utf8mb4_unicode_ci", :database=>"example_development", :pool=>5, :username=>"root", :password=>"password", :socket=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", :flags=>2}>

> @accessible_attribute.first[0]
# => "--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\nattr1:\n- Email id\nattr2:\n- First Name\nattr3:\n- Last Name\n"
```

**Note:** Precisely, Some prefer to take attribute value unserialized by `@user.accessible_attribute.to_yaml` also.

Comment: `YAML.parse(unserialized_column_data).to_ruby` provide hash again